# UITapGestureRecognizer on UIView gets fired after I tap on my MPVolumeSlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I found some questions and answers here on stackoverflow for that problem, but none of  the solutions there solved my problem.

My iOS App has the ability to play some music with a nice music player. I designed it with Xcode's Interface Builder and dragged out a `UIView` and changed its class to `MPVolumeView`. Everything works fine when I'm debugging my app on my iPhone 6.

Here is my problem: I also dragged out a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on my whole view which contains my controls like

> play/pause, next/previous track (...)

and also my `MPVolumeView`. When I tap on that view it should fade out and disappear. Then I added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on my `UIImageView` which shows my artwork image of the song. When I tap this image view, it should fade in my view with all controls in int - that's working properly.

**BUT**: When I slide the knob of the volume slider just a little bit, or if I am just touching it, the view still disappears. It seems like my `MPVolumeView` is forwarding my touch or something like that. I tried setting  `userInteractionEnabled = false`  on my volume slider, but that didn't help. I also set the delegate of my gesture recognizer to *self* and added the

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"tapped");
    if([gestureRecognizer.view isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

function to my code, which returns *true* or *false*, depending on which view I'm tapping. When I'm accessing the *gestureRecognizer.view* property, it doesn't recognize my MPVolumeView, just the UIView in the background.

Here my two methods which are fired after when the `TapGestureRecognizers` are fired:

```
- (IBAction)overlayViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{ self.blackOverlayView.alpha = 0.0; self.normalTimeLabel.alpha = 1.0; }
                     completion:nil];
    }
}
- (IBAction)imageViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{ self.blackOverlayView.alpha = 1.0; self.normalTimeLabel.alpha = 0.0; }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

Please help me, I'm nearly going nuts with that ..

**EDIT**: My music player looks like this:

[image]

After I tap **anywhere** on the view (except the subviews), the view should fade out and hide everything, just show the artwork image of the song and the current elapsed time. This will look like this:

[image]

As I said - the problem is, if I just tap the volume slider or slide it just a little bit, my `UITapGestureRecognizer` fires and fades out my complete view. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Do you mind posting your code? Anything relevant would work. You could post a picture of your storyboard as well...

Comment: OK just a moment please, I'm changing my question.

Comment: Just edited my question, hope you know what I mean.

Comment: I fully understand your problem. The only reason I ask for code is because there could be several corrections and the cause of the problem is not totally clear. If you could take a screenshot of your viewController in your storyboard, and post any code you have written for this viewController, I can be of more assistance.

Comment: I don't have much code to post here, I designed my whole interface using the Interface Builder, dragged out the TapGestureRecognizer onto my UIView (which contains all of my controls) and added my delegate method. There is no code except that lines I already posted. Or what exactly do you want to see?

Comment: Yep, but with using a dirty workaround I think.

Comment: You should post it, and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is behaving the way it is simply because you added the gesture recognizer to the entire `UIView`, which includes the volume slider and whatnot.

Instead of detecting  the touch in the entire view, check to see if the touch is in the area you want it.

Create a `CGRect` property, I'll call it `touchArea`:

```
@property CGRect touchArea;
```

Then specify the size of the `touchArea` (you can do this in the `viewDidLoad`):

```
touchArea  = CGRectMake(0.0, 240.0, 320.0, 240.0);
```

You will have to find out where you want this and how big it should be and replace my example values with the real ones. A simple way of cheating this is to take something like a `UILabel` in IB and positioning and sizing it to your desire, then go to the size inspector pane and get the x, y, width and height values.

Then, before you do your fade animation, check to see if the touch was in the `touchArea`:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(touchArea, touchPoint)) 
    {
        //do your animation here.
    } 
}
```

As a note, I would set a `BOOL` to check whether or not the view is faded in or out, so you can always check before animating.